# java: how to put value elements into a hashmap value array?

Tags: java, hashmap

I was trying to put the int result after rolling a dice into the value of a hashmap. IDE shows error on this line:

```
map.put(1, diceRoll);
```

its explaination is:

```
The method put(Integer, ArrayList<Integer>[]) in the type Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>[]> is not applicable for the arguments (int, ArrayList<Integer>)
```

My code is:

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>[]> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>[]>();
ArrayList<Integer> diceRoll= new ArrayList<Integer>();
Dice dice = new Dice();
diceRoll.add(dice.getLastRoll());

map.put(1, diceRoll); 
ArrayList<Integer>[] integers = map.get(1);
System.out.print(integers[0]);
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store a series of `int`s, you don't need an array of lists, just a list:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> diceRoll = new ArrayList<>();
Dice dice = new Dice();
diceRoll.add(dice.getLastRoll());

map.put(1, diceRoll);
```

Comment: @Jie did you change the declaration of the map like my answer shows?

Comment: Very sorry! I didn't remove the [ ] from `Map<Integer, List<Integer>[]> map`. It's working nicely now. Thank you very much for the help!